# Retrieving every species for every location, ordered by location

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve all species from each location in my input and later do things with it.

```java
String query = "SELECT l.name, d.species " +
                        "FROM entry e " +
                        "INNER JOIN location l ON l.name = e.name " +
                        "INNER JOIN diatom d ON d.taxonKey = e.taxonKey " +
                        "WHERE d.species != '' AND l.name IN ";
```

I use stringbuilder to complete the query.

```java
StringBuilder whereIn = new StringBuilder("(?");
for (int i=0; i < listOfLocations.size()-1; ++i) {
    whereIn.append(", ?");
}
//ORDER BY location.name so i can go through all diatoms per location.
whereIn.append(") ORDER BY l.name");
query += whereIn.toString();
```

simplified database overview:

| diatom |  |
| --- | --- |
| taxonKey | (unique) |
| species | (unique) |

| location |  |
| --- | --- |
| name | (unique) |
| coordinates | (unique) |

| entry |  |
| --- | --- |
| name | (from table location) |
| taxonkey | (from table diatom) |

As my code is now, I'm only retrieving the same repeating set of species for each location and not only the species that are present at a specific location.

What I'm looking to get is roughly something like:

- location 1 species 1
- location 1 species 2
- location 1 species 5
- location 2 species 2
- location 2 species 3
- location 2 species 4

What I'm getting:

- location 1 species 1
- location 1 species 2
- location 1 species 3
- location 2 species 1
- location 2 species 2
- location 2 species 3
- etc.

I have been staring at my query for a while now and I hope someone can help me out with some fresh eyes.

Comment: How about you create us an example here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 ?

Comment: Hi @matthewjava, your insert statements for table Location in this demo are not correct...

Comment: @VBoka I decided to use dbfiddle because i couldn't work out dbfiddle.uk
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqV7BsSddd4qQ1BLgNWv9u/1

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what do you expect to get from this data in your example. P.S. This fiddle is also ok.

Comment: My input is a list of location names, I want all locations with every diatom species that is found at that location. In the fiddle you can see for instance location e, which has 3 inserts in the table Entry, only returns 2 times instead of 3.

Comment: Ok, I see it, but that is only because you did not have the entry that matches taxonKey column in Diatom table. If you enter that value you will get the results you want: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqV7BsSddd4qQ1BLgNWv9u/3   having that in mind, are you sure you are explaining your problem in a right way ?

Comment: maybe my error really isn't in my query, i was so sure about it.... I will close this question and reask it with my whole java code section.